# Checking intersection of arrays

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My table looks like this:

| id | top_id | name_important | name | another_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 |  |  | [AAA, BBB] | null |
| 222 | 111 | [AAA] |  | X |

What I would like to check is that `top_id` and `name_important` are not empty. And that value in  array `name_important` are in array `name` based on `top_id` (those arrays might be empty or might not exisit). In this case there is the relation between `id` 222 and 111 because `id` 222 has 111 in column `top_id`. I would like to return `true` or `false`. Could you help me?

I would like to use case when clause since I have other cases to include, something like this:

```sql
with test as (
  select 111 as id, null as top_id, null as name_important, ["AAA", "BBB"] as name, null as another_column union all
  select 222, 111, ["AAA"], null, X
)

select id,
case when another_column is not null then true
when (question in the topic) then true
else false end result
from test
```

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: I would like to include checking described above in the case when clause and return true or false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this could fit:

```
with test as (
  select 111 as id, null as top_id, null as name_important, ["AAA", "BBB"] as name, null as another_column union all
  select 222, 111, ["AAA"], null, "X"
)
select 
  id,
  case 
    when another_column is not null then true
    when intersected then true
    else false
  end result
from (
  select test.*, ifnull(intersected, false) as intersected
  from test
  left join (
    select secondary.id, true as intersected
    from (
      select test.id, name
      from test, test.name as name
    ) as main
    join (
      select test.id, test.top_id, name_important
      from test, test.name_important as name_important
    ) as secondary
    on main.id = secondary.top_id and main.name = secondary.name_important
  ) using (id)
)
```

[image]

Comment: And how would you approach this if I have case when clause and I would like to do another when for this case?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Examples would be very helpful.

Comment: I have something like this:
```
select id,
case when top_id is not null then true else
when name_important is not null else
when (question in this topic) then true else false end
from test
```

Comment: Still hard to follow... Could add examples of the input data and the desired output data?

Comment: The rest of the code doesn't really matter but I will update the question with this. What matters is that I want to check for each id that columns: `top_id` and `name_important` aren't null + values in column `name_important` exist in column `name` (but in id based on the id from `top_id`) => I want this to be in case when clause. If the requirements are met then I want to use `true` otherwise `false`

Comment: Added `intersected` column

Comment: I have updated the question, could help me with this now? Your logic is good, maybe I should create a function based on your query and use it in the when statement?

Comment: Well... you can envelope it. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your example if you need *all* values in the array to match or *any* values.  If you want *any* value, then:

```
with test as (
  select 111 as id, null as top_id, null as name_important, ['AAA', 'BBB'] as name union all
  select 222, 111, ['AAA'], null
)
select t2.*, t1.name
from test t1 join
     test t2
     on t1.top_id = t2.id
where t1.name_important is not null and
      exists (select 1
              from unnest(t2.name) n1 join 
                   unnest(t1.name_important) n2
                   on n2 = n1
             )
```

If all need to match:

```
with test as (
  select 111 as id, null as top_id, null as name_important, ['AAA', 'BBB'] as name union all
  select 222, 111, ['AAA'], null
)
select t1.*, t2.name
from test t1 join
     test t2
     on t1.top_id = t2.id
where t1.name_important is not null and
      not exists (select 1
                  from unnest(t1.name_important) n1 left join
                       unnest(t2.name) n2  
                       on n2 = n1
                  where n2 is null
                 );
```